# Javascript, function scope and return operator

Tags: javascript

I have a written a simple javascript function that will write the variable value that is outside of the function using `document.write` and call the function. However, the code doesn't work:

```
var name = 'guru';
function type () {
  document.write = name;
}
```

I then tried returning `document.write`. However, this also did not work.

```
var name = 'guru';
function type () {
  return document.write = name;
}
type();
```

In this code, I just return the variable and use `document.write` outside of the function. This works.

```
var name = 'guru';
function type () {
    return name;
}
document.write = type();
```

Why is this happening? Can someone explain this to me?

**edit**

The code here doesn't work in firebug, because the firebug outside HTML5 document doesn't recognize `document.write` as a function, see the error in the image. That is if you fire up *firebug* and run this doesn't work but if it is run inside a HTML DOM this is an error, this is a bug or this is how it works.

[image: firebug error]

Comment: I think you need `document.write (somevariable)`

Comment: Did you intend to *call* the `document.write` function? Because none of the three versions seem to do that. They redefine `document.write` instead.

Comment: as @HoboSapiens pointed out document.write is function

Comment: @HoboSapiens nope !!  because _firbug_ doesn't recognize `document.write` as a function, this is correct according to _firebug_ . Wait I ll try it with in the HTML DOM.

Comment: do you mean "document.write(name)"?

Comment: @yangguang yup but when used in firebug as a function it returns an `error`

Comment: @CoDINGinDARK you have a few good answers. You should accept one (if it helped you solve your problem)—it's considered good etiquette on SO.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write), but if you absolutely must:

```
var writeSomething = function (message) {
    document.write(message);
}
```

If you're trying to debug, I recommend using [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log). It's supported by all modern browsers and is much more useful (it lets you inspect objects, arrays, etc.). The problem with `document.write` is that it destroys the current document to write the new information (see note at end).

Here's an example use of this function:

```js
var writeSomething = function (message) {
    document.write(message);
}

document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
    var message = document.getElementById("myMessage").value;
    writeSomething(message);
}
```

```html
<button id="myButton">click me</button>
<input id="myMessage" placeholder="type message here">
```

**from MDN on why `document.write` is a no-no**:

> Note: as `document.write` writes to the document **stream**, calling `document.write` on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls `document.open` [which will clear the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open).

tl;dr? avoid `document.write` like the plague.

Answer (score 2):

The `document.write` is a function.
The syntax is as follows:

```
document.write(exp1,exp2,exp3,...)
```

The parameters are optional. Multiple arguments can be listed and they will be appended to the document in order of occurrence

Answer (score 2):

`document.write` is a `function`, which you need to `call` like so:

```
var myHtml = "<html><head></head><body><div><span>Hello World!</span></div></body></html>";

document.write(myHtml);
```

Answer (score 2):

A.

```
function type() {
var name = 'guru';  
 document.write (name);
}
```

B.

```
var name = 'guru';
  function type( text ) {
  document.write(text);

  }
  type( name );
```

You have do this like this.Look at it once,it helps you to under stand.

Comment: You should **not** return `document.write(arguments)`; that'll only ever return `undefined`, since `document.write` is the equivalent of a `void` function.

Comment: Setting `document.write` equal to `x`, before returning `x`, is no different.

Comment: There should be no return value wii be there i think.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `document.write = name;`, you are overwriting the function.

You must use it like: `document.write(message);`

http://codepen.io/ces/pen/GJoxbX

Answer (score 2):

According to [document.write syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) you should pass it an argument that will be actual DOM string.

By doing

```
function type() {
return name;
}
document.write = type();
```

You you actually overwrite the original `document.write` function. So now if you call `document.write('foo')` you will get `Uncaught TypeError: document.write is not a function`. 
Proper way however of using `document.write` could be:

```
document.write("<h1>Foo</h1>");
```